# Ubuntu 12.04.2 startup waits on splash screen and loads desktop only after pressing TAB

Tags: boot, startup, plymouth

Ubuntu on startup shows the splash screen(with the dots rotating animation going on and on).
And only when I press TAB key it stops and the desktop loads.
What may be the problem?

Am having ubuntu 12.04.2 installed through wubi and with kernel 3.5.0-21-generic.

Comment: Boot without boot logo to find out more: When rebooting hold the shift key pressed so that the GRUB2 menu is shown. There select the Ubuntu Entry and press the 'e' key to edit the command line. Remove the 'splash' and 'quiet' options. When the boot process hangs, note the last (few) line(s) and add them to your question.

Comment: Sure.. Do that and update the question. Thanks.